# how to skip first line in python using read() function?

Tags: python

I just wanted to know if whether there is a way to skip the first line of a text file,by ONLY using read() to read the file and NOT readlines()

Comment: You can't. But you can use `readline` to read just one line. Why do you want to do it with `read`?

Comment: You can use `readline()` (not `readlines()` - note the `s`) to read the first line only, and then `read()` to read the rest, effectively skipping the first line.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to iterate over the file somehow to decide when you've gotten to a line. But you can use `readline` instead of `readlines` to just read *one line*, not all lines, from the file. That's almost certainly what you want:

```py
fd = open('file.txt')
first_line = fd.readline()    #
rest_of_file = fd.read()     # All but the first line
```

Notice it's not plural. `readline` instead of readline**s**

Comment: Nice answer, I believe he's been asking for solution without readline.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko, I assumed he was looking for a solution without **readlines**, which reads all the lines.

Comment: makes sense :) !

Answer (score 0):

The readline is correct way of doing so, since your point is on achieving that without readline, you can do it with [os.linesep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep):

```
import os

fpath = __file__

with open(fpath, 'r') as f:
  candidate = None
  while candidate != os.linesep:
    try:
        candidate = f.read(1)
        print("Read a character:", candidate)
    except Exception:
        break
  content_after_first_line = f.read()

print(content_after_first_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way :)

```
file = open('path/file.txt','r')
lines = file.readlines()[1:] #this will skip 1st line
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are restricted to only use `read()`, you can do this in a loop, providing a size as an argument to `read()`. If you reach the newline-separator `'\n'`, you can exit the loop as you have reached the end of the first line.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    char = f.read(1)
    while char != '\n':
        char = f.read(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `next()` on the file handle:

```
with open('file.txt') as f_in:
    next(f_in)  # skip the first line
    print(f_in.read())
```